# Creating file with non-editable parts

Tags: file, templates, clojure

Is it possible in Clojure to spit a file that has non-editable parts, as if you are creating a template, and you want certain entries in it. The user can opt to fill in the values of these entries, but not being able to play with the entries themselves?

Comment: I guess, it depends on the file format that will be produced. In an HTML file, I can probably get this done by creating a map where the non-editable parts are the keys, and the editable parts are the values (a div with a textarea) that the user can fill.

Comment: What is this in the context of? "Non-editable" parts of an arbitrary text file?

Comment: @carcigenicate Sorry for not responding earlier. What you mentioned was the initial idea. Then when I though about it, I found it it made sense when the file format is an html file. It would be great if this applies to a text file as well, but I have no idea how this can be achieved. Let me elaborate in another comment.

Comment: @carcigenicate My initial thinking is that the core of the solution will be a collection of key-value pairs, where the keys will represent the non-editable parts, and the values can be changed by the intended user(s). But how this can be achieved in a text file?

Comment: @carcigenicate I also think that this need to exist in a controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine user input (values) to a "non-editable" template by using a configuration file that is separate from the template. This has the additional benefit that you can implement validation for the user input in the config file with moderate effort.

An example that uses a vanilla Clojure `.edn` config file and a simple string template with regex substitution for the values:

*config.edn*

```
{:first-name "Toni"
 :last-name  "Vanhala"}
```

*core.clj*

```
(ns template-engine
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (java.io FileReader PushbackReader)))

(def TEMPLATE ["Hi :first-name,"
               "Your completed form:"
               "First name: :first-name"
               "Last name:  :last-name"])

(def ^:private KW-REGEX #":([^,\s]+)")

(defn- get-config-val [config raw-val]
  (->> raw-val
       (second)
       (keyword)
       (get config)))

(defn format-line [config line]
  (let [get-val (partial get-config-val config)]
    (clojure.string/replace line KW-REGEX get-val)))

(defn- read-config [^String filename]
  (let [stream (-> filename
                   (FileReader.)
                   (PushbackReader.))
        config (clojure.edn/read stream)]
    (->> TEMPLATE
         (map #(format-line config %))
         (clojure.string/join "\n")
         (println))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (when-let [filename (first args)]
    (read-config filename)))
```

After compiling this, you can run it on the command line with a spell similar to:
`java -jar template-engine.jar config.edn`

You may want to consider using a more sophisticated template engine for formatting the output. Take a look at, e.g., [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer). Even [cl-format](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format) may be worth considering. If `.edn` files are too "Clojure-like" for your users, you can use another format for the config file as well. There are Clojure [YAML](https://github.com/owainlewis/yaml) and [JSON](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) parsers, for example.

Comment: Many thanks for responding. I am shy to say that I couldn't configure the project, even with you remarks for config.edn, and core.clj. This is really embarrassing. I am just making my Clojure infancy steps.

Comment: Ok. I made it, and managed to configure the project. This might work, but it is not exactly what I want. Anyways thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Ok. I made it, and managed to configure the project. The provided solution might work, but it is not exactly what I want. I almost want the opposite of what your solution suggests. I want to produce the template through code, where the keys are not-editable and the values are "open" for the user to start inputting. It is like a form in a web app, where users can enter the values, but can't mess the form types or labels. The config.edn is like an "open" file that the user can play with any part of it.

Anyways, thanks for your time and effort